# jquery jplayer flash fallback not working

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have a jquery jplayer whose html version works fine. When I try to load the flash version as the default one, it stops working.

When I load the page Chrome console shows the error "PPB_Graphics2D.PaintImageData: Rectangle is outside bounds" twice. Firefox doesn't show any JS error.

Here is the jQuery code.

```
     $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            solution:"flash, html",
            play: function() { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
                 $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
            },
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                     mp3: "http://test.com/music.mp3"

                  });
             },

             swfPath: "player/jplayer",
             supplied: "mp3",
             cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp-audio-container1"
   });
```

If I reverse the solution to solution: "html, flash", the player works fine.
This is the flash player generated by the script:

```
   <embed name="jp_flash_0" id="jp_flash_0" src="player/jplayer/Jplayer.swf" width="0" height="0" bgcolor="#000000" quality="high" flashvars="id=jquery_jplayer_1&amp;vol=0.8&amp;muted=false" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; ">
```

Verified that the mp3 url is working fine. I have also verified(using Chrome Network) that the JPlayer.swf file path is correct and is accessible from the above code.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error "PPB_Graphics2D.PaintImageData: Rectangle is outside bounds" normally happens because of the PepperFlash plugin of Chrome. Some solutions suggest disabling it. That did not work for me.

After a lot of searching around, I solved it by downloading a fresh jquery.jplayer.min.js. Not sure what was wrong with the other one.

**[EDIT]** It happened to me again during the development. Noting down the result, for the benefit of anyone else having same issue. I used the **debug version of Flash plugin for Chrome** to troubleshoot this.  The error was because JPlayer was not found on the relative URL specified in the "swf" attribute. After spending considerable time with jPlayer, *looks like the two things to check in the  event of an swf error are - the swf path and the version of JPlayer.swf.*